# WiX standard UI for username and password

Tags: wix, wix3.6, bootstrapper, burn

I am working on doing a proof of concept for a new bootstrapper that will be built using Burn. So far, I have managed to get everything to work just fine. It has gone better than expected, to be honest.

The only thing that I have been unable to nail down is how to get the build in WiX UI to ask for a service username and password, then send it to the appropriate MSI. Is there anything built in to do this?

In a more general question, are there any great resources for getting started with, or getting the most out of, Burn?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question - but if anyone comes here looking, here's a way to pass information to your MSIs. You can set the MsiProperty of the MsiPackage in your bundle, then use `Engine.StringVariables` to set/get them. For example:

```
<MsiPackage Id="PackageID" SourceFile="C:\Location...\Package.msi" DownloadUrl="https://downloadurl/Package.msi">
   <MsiProperty Name="MyProperty" Value="[MyProperty]"/>
</MsiPackage>
```